# Load different resources on urlUpdate elm

Tags: elm

I am new to elm and functional programming. Hope this is a simple question. What I am trying to do is, when I change views I want elm to fetch records based on the view that it is about to change to. I was hoping I could do it in the urlUpdate method based on the currentRoute. I have two views one for players and one for perks, both have independent commands objects. I tried to do it like this:

```elm
urlUpdate : Result String Route -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
urlUpdate result model =
    let
        currentRoute =
            Routing.routeFromResult result

        _ =
            Debug.log "Current Route" currentRoute
    in
        if toString currentRoute == "PerksRoute" then
            ( { model | route = currentRoute }
            , Perks.Commands.fetchAll
            )
        else if toString currentRoute == "PlayersRoute" then
            ( { model | route = currentRoute }
            , Players.Commands.fetchAll
            )
        else
            ( { model | route = currentRoute }, Cmd.none )
```

However I get this error:

> The 1st branch has this type:
>
> ```elm
>    ( { a | route : Route }, Cmd Perks.Messages.Msg )
> ```
>
> But the 2nd is:
>
> ```elm
>    ( { a | route : Route }, Cmd Players.Messages.Msg )
> ```

I am not sure why this is happening, I would think that having this Type defined at would be ok.

```elm
type Msg
    = PlayersMsg Players.Messages.Msg
    | PerksMsg Perks.Messages.Msg
```

Here is the full [src](https://github.com/mdemin914/elm-playground/tree/master)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`Cmd.map`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.0/Platform-Cmd#map) to map the child command to the parent:

```elm
if toString currentRoute == "PerksRoute" then
    ( { model | route = currentRoute }
    , Cmd.map PerksMsg Perks.Commands.fetchAll
    )
else if toString currentRoute == "PlayersRoute" then
    ( { model | route = currentRoute }
    , Cmd.map PlayersMsg Players.Commands.fetchAll
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works! Could you please explain what that is doing, I was looking at the docs and still can't quite wrap my head around it. The signature for Cmd.map is (a -> msg) -> Cmd a -> Cmd msg. The first argument is PlayersMsg which is not a function?

Comment: `PlayersMsg` and `PerksMsg` are both type constructors, each of which take a single argument and return a `Messages.Msg` value. Type constructors can be thought of as functions in this sense, and that's why they fit into `Cmd.map` as the first parameter.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense looking at the `type Msg
    = PlayersMsg Players.Messages.Msg
    | PerksMsg Perks.Messages.Msg
    | PicturesMsg Pictures.Messages.Msg
    | NavMsg Components.Nav.Messages.Msg` ! Thanks for the info.

Comment: I am still getting used to the awesomeness of the elm type system and the compiler telling me really usefull things.